# React Native 0.63.3 unable to resolve module ./Libraries/Components/AccessibilityInfo/AccessibilityInfo

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm stuck on this error for 2 days now

```
Unable to resolve module ./Libraries/Components/AccessibilityInfo/AccessibilityInfo
```

I tried to deleted node modules, clear cache, but still no luck

Im using React Native `0.63.3` and React `16.13.1`

Please help

Comment: Did you recently upgrade react-native? Perhaps you forgot to update any other dependencies, use https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/ to guide you through your upgrade process

Answer (score 0):

Can you try deleting podfile.lock and package-lock.json and run

`watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-* && rm -rf node_modules/ && npm cache verify && npm install --legacy-peer-deps && cd ios/ && rm -rf build && rm -rf Pods && pod install && cd .. && npm start -- --reset-cache`